# Update open/done dialog not coming after package installer?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

Currently My application has the update feature and i'm unable to show the open/done dilaog after the package installer? Is there any another alternative then suggest me. thanks :-)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(apkPath)), " application/vnd.android.package-archive");
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

How do I show the Open/done dialog after the package Installation?

Comment: use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity & show open/done dialog in onActivityResult() method..

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate() method use `startActivityForResult` instead on `startActivity` & send additional 1000 as `requestCode`. You can receive that value inside `onActivityResult()` method & you can show success or failure dialog inside `onActivityResult()` method as given below

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(apkPath)), "   application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  startActivityForResult(intent, 1000); //1000 is RequestCode here

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check for resultCode == RESULT_OK & requestCode == 1000 conditions 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1000) {
            System.out.println("Success Status");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failure Status");
        }

    }
```